# What hardware factors affect .NET compile times?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to get my company to invest in developer appropriate hardware. As part of that discussion, I need to provide information on what hardware most affects (especially) .NET compile times. This will be used to try and get the best bang for the buck possible. Links or discussions of why the hardware is important would really be appreciated! I'm thinking CPU, memory, Disk IO are primary, but I'm not sure which gets you the biggest bang for the buck.

Comment: We recently replaced all magnetic drives with SSD drives and the difference it made was phenomenal.

Comment: I agree. SSD's will have the most impact, then memory imo and only then CPU.